# PHP / SQL запрос на добавление даты

Tags: php

В таблице БД mysql есть поле типа *DATETIME*

В переменной хранить дата в таком формате: `$dt = "29.03.14 14:23"`

Нужно составить *sql-запрос* на добавление этой даты в поле БД.

Может перед запросом, дату нужно переформатировать через `date()` ?

Нужно что бы в БД, дата записалась так: `2014-03-29 00:00:00`

т.е. время меня не интересует, только дата, хотя это не столь важно...

Answer (score 1):

Верно, надо форматировать поле при помощи date. Используйте формат `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` для даты/времени или просто `"Y-m-d"` для даты (и в БД сделайте тип `DATE` вместо `DATETIME`, раз уж вам время не нужно)